# Job on specific day of week

Tags: linux, cron, centos

I want to have a job running on 5 pm every Wed, Sat and Sun... will this be correct?

> 0 17 * * 0,3,6 my.command.goes.here.

PS: using centos

Answer (score 0):

As of my recent research about cron, what you wrote is correct.

It would not hurt much to search google for crontab manual ;)
http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/crontab.5.php

Comment: apparently, the cron job is not running... any clue? anyway i run it not as root... but another userid, using crontab -e

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the issue.. it is Linux issue regarding time.

i use hwclock, it display time A.
i use grep to see cron time, it display time B
i use php to echo time, it display time C.

funny, they all have different time.

linux never cease to amaze me....